Failure of physical device to connect to correct port where flask server is running
I have a flutter application and it makes use of a REST API which is running as a flask server on port 5000 locally on my host machine but when I install the app on my physical device it seems to be accessing the wrong port how to fix this issue
I tried making changes to the androidmanifest file but that did not help much and tried to put the problem on chatgpt as well that didn't help much too

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The problem was with assigning the host adress to my api which I had not done set host=0.0.0 inside the if_main block of the API and set port to a fixed port 5000 in my case and change the flutter code accordingly
